# Angular 6 POST to Amazon S3 error 412 - no file in FormData and incorrect enctype

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3

So I'm trying to send a file to Amazon S3 bucket using standard Angular HTTP POST method.

Here is the code in question:

```
public postFileToS3(file: File, params: any, url: string): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders(params);
    headers.set('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    formData.append('Content-Type', file.type);
    formData.append('key', file.name);
    formData.append('name', file.name);
    formData.append('enctype ', 'multipart/form-data');
    Object.keys(params).forEach(key => {
        formData.append(key, params[key]);
    });
    return this.http.post(url, formData, {headers: headers});
}
```

And credentials params passed to it that I'm getting from S3 and a File that I'm trying to send:

```
private uploadFile(file: File, fileNames: string[], masterProjectId: number): void {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    if (!this.supportedMimeTypes.test(file.type)) {
        return this.informAboutErrors();
    }

    reader.onprogress = this.onProgressHandler();
    reader.onload = () => {
        fileNames.push(file.name);
        this.api.getS3FormData(file.type, masterProjectId).subscribe((response) => {
            const s3Directory = [this.api.getDirectory(file.type)];
            const inputs = response['inputs'];
            const key = (s3Directory.length ? s3Directory.join('/') + '/' : '') + file.name;
            this._url = response['url'];
            this._uploadParams['Content-Type'] = file.type;
            this._uploadParams['acl'] = inputs['acl'];
            this._uploadParams['success_action_status'] = inputs['success_action_status'];
            this._uploadParams['policy'] = inputs['policy'];
            this._uploadParams['X-amz-credential'] = inputs['X-amz-credential'];
            this._uploadParams['X-amz-algorithm'] = inputs['X-amz-algorithm'];
            this._uploadParams['X-amz-date'] = inputs['X-amz-date'];
            this._uploadParams['X-amz-expires'] = inputs['X-amz-expires'];
            this._uploadParams['X-amz-signature'] = inputs['X-amz-signature'];
            this._uploadParams['key'] = key;
            if (response) {
                this.api.postFileToS3(file, this._uploadParams, response['url']).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
            }
        });
    };

    if (file) {
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }
}
```

So in theory everything should be working fine, I'm authenticated and POST is sending, but I'm getting a 412 error - "Precondition Failed" with error message saying "At least one of the pre-conditions you specified did not hold. Bucket POST must be of the enclosure-type multipart/form-data".

I've tried setting "enctype" on both headers and FormData, but no luck there. Also here is the full request from Chrome Dev Tools:

```
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
acl: private
Content-Type: audio/mp3
key: voice_tests/sample.mp3
Origin: https://localhost:4200
policy:xxx
Referer: https://localhost:4200/app/casting-setup/7782/29867
success_action_status: 201
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36
X-amz-algorithm: xxx
X-amz-credential: xxx
X-amz-date: xxx
X-amz-expires: xxx
X-amz-signature: xxx
```

It look like there is no file in FormData and maybe that's the problem. I also found some GitHub issue in Angular repo with some people saying that sending FormData with this enctype is not working for them either.

I will appreciate all the help I can get. I know there is a great aws-sdk package, but right now I have to do it this way.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try PUT instead of POST?

Comment: Yes, changing http.post to http.put results in a 400 error with message saying "The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema".